# Write array of variable size to file

Tags: python, hdf5

I'm developing a `python` program that needs to write some data of the form "time step - quantity" to the file. The size of data is determined during runtime. Now I do it this way (schematics):

```py
f = open('data.txt', 'w')

while not condition:
    time_step += 1
    q = compute_q()
    f.write('{0:d} {1:.3e}'.format(time_step, q))
```

**My question**: is it OK do it this way? Or I should bufferize data somehow and than dump the buffer to the file? What should I do if I switch to the binary format such as `hdf5`? Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at `pickle/cPickle`, they tend to cover most writing problems, depends on the data type though.

Comment: Taking this as pseudo-code: Why shouldn't it be OK?  You seem concerned about performance, but that should only bother you if the amount of data is huge and / or the program runs very frequently.  Buffering is typically not necessary - the operating system will most likely take care of it sufficiently.  And, finally: switching from a textual file format to a binary one should also only done if there is real need.

Comment: Your sample is fine -- file I/O is buffered automatically with standard file objects.

Comment: Thank you, all, this is what I want it to learn - whether  buffering is done automatically, because, obviously I don't want to do small frequent writes to a disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your needs. If you are concerned about the throughput, you should buffer your writes. Use the `buffering` parameter of [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about this parameter.